# What new changes came with Swing in Java 8?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-8

Are there any changes than came with Swing and AWT in Java 8? In release notes for Java 8 I it's not mentioned.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/swing/enhancements-8.html … yeah, looks a bit thin…

Answer (score 7):

I don't think so...
Swing has really old API, oracle left it behind in favor of JavaFX - which does have (and still developed) methods that use the new APIs.

Edit: just remembered, the only new 'feature' that I know of that was added to swing is the JFXPanel which is a way of integrating JavaFX components into your app [swing-fx-interoperability](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)